# Authentication Flow in React

Tags: authentication, reactjs, store, redux

I have an application that has authentication at the container level (way out) and I'm using redux-auth-wrapper for authenticated components.

Within those components, I will want to make authenticated calls affecting local state only. Sometimes the server may return a 401, in which case I know I need to refresh my token with something like this: `status === 401 && myLoginAction()`

The structure looks something like this:

```
Container [Connects to root store with auth]
 |- Auth
 |- Login
 |- Authenticated page wrapped with redux-auth-wrapper
    |- Action to update state, needs to be authenticated
```

---

#### Questions:

1. Where should my authenticated action live? Can I call it in from the higher namespace into my component?
2. Can I wrap my lower action with an authentication action? Is there a good example out there somewhere? I've only ever seen single-store authentication. Or is that how I should handle this?
3. How do I access a login action from within the lower component?